# Is there a newer date coverflow for Android that does not use deprecated methods?

Tags: android, coverflow

I was looking into some coverflow solutions, but the one based on Neil Davis code, Polidea example (based on Neil Davis code), and some third anonymous solution, they all use deprecated widgets or deprecated methods.

(Gallery widget, GestureDetector, ...)

Is there any library similar to mentioned but of newer date without deprecations?

Tnx

Comment: Please check this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26311469/android-coverflow-without-gallery

Comment: Please check this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26311469/android-coverflow-without-gallery

Answer (score 4):

Instead of gallery widget you can use horizontal scroll view.In horizontal scroll view add linearLayout of horizontal orientation and add child views(images) to linear layout.By using left of the child and center of screen you can rotate the images.Its working for me.All the best

or you can use neil davis code which extends CoverAbsSpinner. In coverflow constructor change mGestureDetector=new GestureDetector(context,this).In GestureDetector all constructor are not deprecated.

Comment: Yes, an example would be great!